# Getting coordinates and drawing polylines from bitmap in .net

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I´m using `netDxf` to convert a `.dxf` file to a bitmap, and I can't figure out how to get the polyline's vertices coordinates, and then draw it using `.net`.

```
using netDxf.Entities;
using netDxf;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;



namespace teste_bitmap
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadDxfFile();
        }

        private void LoadDxfFile()
        {
            string filePath = "C:/molde 2.dxf";

            try
            {
                DxfDocument dxfDocument = DxfDocument.Load(filePath);

                if (dxfDocument == null)
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }

                else 
                {
                    // Get the Image object from DrawDxfEntities method
                    System.Drawing.Image image = DrawDxfEntities(dxfDocument);
                    // Display the image in a PictureBox
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                }

                string entityInfoText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, entityInfos);
                MessageBox.Show(entityInfoText, "Entity Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            catch { }
        }

        public System.Drawing.Image DrawDxfEntities(DxfDocument dxfDocument)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graphics.Clear(Color.White);

            foreach (var block in dxfDocument.Blocks)
            {
                foreach (var entity in block.Entities)
                {
                    DrawDxfEntity(graphics, entity);
                }
            }

            return bitmap;
        }

        static List<string> entityInfos = new List<string>();

        static void DrawDxfEntity(Graphics graphics, EntityObject entity)
        {

            string entityInfo = string.Empty;

            if (entity is Line line)
            {
                entityInfo = $"Processing Line: StartPoint=({line.StartPoint.X}, {line.StartPoint.Y}), EndPoint=({line.EndPoint.X}, {line.EndPoint.Y})";
                graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, (float)line.StartPoint.X, (float)line.StartPoint.Y, (float)line.EndPoint.X, (float)line.EndPoint.Y);
            }
            else if (entity is Circle circle)
            {
                entityInfo = $"Processing Circle: Center=({circle.Center.X}, {circle.Center.Y}), Radius={circle.Radius}";
                graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, (float)(circle.Center.X - circle.Radius), (float)(circle.Center.Y - circle.Radius),
                    (float)(2 * circle.Radius), (float)(2 * circle.Radius));
            }


            else if (entity is Arc arc)

            {

                entityInfo = $"Processing Arc: Start Angle=({arc.StartAngle}), End Angle=({arc.EndAngle}), Radius={arc.Radius}";
                double sweepAngle = arc.EndAngle - arc.StartAngle;
                arc.EndAngle = sweepAngle;

                graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Black, (float)(arc.Center.X - arc.Radius), (float)(arc.Center.Y - arc.Radius),

                    (float)(2 * arc.Radius), (float)(2 * arc.Radius), (float)arc.StartAngle, (float)arc.EndAngle);
            }

            else if (entity is Polyline2D polyline)
            {
                
            }

            entityInfos.Add(entityInfo);

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to get the vertices by using
`polyline.Vertexes`
but I can't draw them with
`graphics.DrawLines()`
because it needs to be `PointF` and I can't get the coordinates of each vertex

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? I would be surprised if there is no way to get X/Y coordinates from something called a "vertex"

Comment: I couldn't find anything, and I'm also new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting the vertex coordinates to PointF.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

else if (entity is Polyline2D polyline)
{
    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();

    foreach (var vertex in polyline.Vertexes)
    {
        points.Add(new PointF((float)vertex.Position.X, (float)vertex.Position.Y));
    }

    entityInfo = $"Processing Polyline: Vertices={polyline.Vertexes.Count}";
    graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points.ToArray());
}
```

With this code you will iterate through each vertex in Polyline2D, then convert the coordinates to PointF and add it to the list of points, and finally `graphics.DrawLines()` to draw the polyline.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf/blob/master/netDxf/Entities/Polyline2DVertex.cs) for Polyline2DVertex, it as a Position-property of Vector2, and that should have the X/y parameters.

I often add an extension method for doing conversions between such simple types:

```
public static class PointExtensions
{
        public static PointF ToPointF(this Vector2 p) => new Point(p.X, p.Y);
}
```

That way it becomes fairly easy to convert the whole list PointF:

```
var points = polyline.Vertexes.Select(v => v.Position.ToPointF());
```